# Go straight to the image taken after using the camera

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

There are loads of great tutorials to go to the photo gallery after you have used the camera and then select your picture but I need to go  straight to the picture.

What I need is to be able to simulate what the Iphone does after it takes a picture...it displays the picture straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps:

- Take picture using `UIImagePickerController`
- Implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`
- In this method, save it to iPhone photo album
- Also display the same image using [`UIImageView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to your view

Here is the [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) provided by apple and here is [tutorial reference](http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html)

Hope this will help you.

Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help , i implemented this way but it seemed to always go to the library and not the last picture taken. Using the assets library system it all works good now..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at alassetlibrary documentation which might be of great help.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks , asset library code takes me straight to the picture..awesome